# How to sort data by alphabetical order by removing numbers at the beginning of the name

Tags: r, gsub

I'm trying to sort these state names by alphabetical order while retaining the number to the left of the state name. I currently cannot figure out how to do this.

I've tried using various forms of `gsub` in an attempt to remove the numbers before sorting without any success.

This is the dataset with the states:

```
print(StateRankings)

# [1] "1. Arizona"         "10. Missouri"       "11. Tennessee"      "12. Florida"       
# [5] "13. West Virginia"  "14. Kentucky"       "15. New Hampshire"  "16. Mississippi"   
# [9] "17. Wyoming"        "18. Alabama"        "19. Idaho"           "2. Alaska"         
#[13] "20. Vermont"        "21. Indiana"        "22. Arkansas"       "23. Wisconsin"     
#[17] "24. South Carolina" "25. Nevada"         "26. North Carolina" "27. Michigan"      
#[21] "28. Louisiana"      "29. Ohio"           "3. Kansas"          "30. Maine"         
#[25] "31. Virginia"       "32. South Dakota"   "33. Pennsylvania"   "34. Oregon"        
#[29] "35. Nebraska"       "36. Iowa"           "37. New Mexico"     "38. Washington"    
#[33] "39. Colorado"       "4. Oklahoma"        "40. Illinois"       "41. Minnesota"     
#[37] "42. Delaware"       "43. Rhode Island"   "44. Maryland"       "45. Connecticut"   
#[41] "46. California"     "47. Hawaii"         "48. New Jersey"     "49. Massachusetts" 
#[45] "5. Montana"         "50. New York"       "6. Utah"             "7. North Dakota"   
#[49] "8. Texas"           "9. Georgia"
```

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the numbers and dot from the character vector, then use `order` to sort only the names and subset the original vector.

```
StateRankings[order(sub("^\\d+\\.\\s+", "", StateRankings))]

#[1] "18. Alabama"  "2. Alaska"  "1. Arizona"  "12. Florida"  "19. Idaho"        
# 6] "14. Kentucky"  "16. Mississippi"  "10. Missouri" "15. New Hampshire"     
#[10] "11. Tennessee" "13. West Virginia" "17. Wyoming"
```

Just FYI, R has inbuilt state names which is in ascending order stored in `state.name`

```
state.name
#[1] "Alabama"   "Alaska"  "Arizona"  "Arkansas"  "California" "Colorado"
#[7] "Connecticut"  "Delaware"  "Florida"   "Georgia"  "Hawaii" "Idaho"........
```

**data**

```
StateRankings <- c("1. Arizona", "10. Missouri", "11. Tennessee" ,"12. Florida",
 "13. West Virginia" ,"14. Kentucky", "15. New Hampshire", "16. Mississippi",
 "17. Wyoming", "18. Alabama", "19. Idaho" ,"2. Alaska")
```

Comment: God bless your soul. Thank you so much.